# Is this calculation of a change of variable correct?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a metric with the form

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\dfrac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma} \cos^2\theta+\dfrac{\beta\gamma}{\alpha}\sin^2\theta & \dfrac{\beta}{\gamma\alpha} (\gamma^2-\alpha^2)\cos\theta\sin\theta & 0\\
\dfrac{\beta}{\gamma\alpha} (\gamma^2-\alpha^2)\cos\theta\sin\theta & \dfrac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma} \sin^2\theta+\dfrac{\beta\gamma}{\alpha}\cos^2\theta&0\\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{\alpha\gamma}{\beta}\sin^2\theta
\end{array} \right)$$

which can be brought to a diagonal form with the change of variables:
$$d\theta \cos\theta+dr\sin\theta=dX$$
$$d\theta \sin\theta - dr \sin\theta= dY$$

Is it correct to say that the variable $X$ and $Y$ are related to $\theta$ and $r$ by:
$$X=r\sin\theta$$
$$Y=-r\cos\theta \, ?$$

I think that one can go from the second expression to the differential one because the correct differential for $\theta$ is $\dfrac{1}{r}d\theta$. Is this correct?

Comment: This really looks like a natural metric on SL(2,R), is it?

Comment: @Dinisaur yes it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change of variable $X=X(\theta,r)$ and $Y=Y(\theta,r)$ that gives you that differential.

Recall that $$dX=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}X(\theta,r)d\theta+\frac{\partial}{\partial r}X(\theta,r)dr$$ and $$dY=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}Y(\theta,r)d\theta+\frac{\partial}{\partial r}Y(\theta,r)dr$$
You can check that these equations have no solutions in your case.
Another way to see it is recalling that if you differentiate twice you must get zero $d^2X=0$. So in general, in order to have $df=\Sigma_ig_idx_i$ for some functions $g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $i=1,\dots,n$, these needs to satisfy the conditions $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g_j=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}g_i$$
In this case this amounts to ask $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\cos\theta$$ and $$-\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\sin\theta=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\sin\theta$$
In other words we can say that the forms $$d\theta\cos\theta+dr\sin\theta$$ and $$d\theta\sin\theta-dr\sin\theta$$ are not exact.